# How do I add multiple main files to Angular CLI project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In angular-cli.json there is entry `"index": "index.html",` that tells Webpack where to bootrap Angular as SPA. I would like to run Angular on multiple main .HTML files like search.html, list.html etc. How do I tell CLI that these .HTML files should also embed Angular code like it does for index.html?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your request, Angular is specifically designed to build SPA. The navigation between "page" is logical and done through component that will change the whole page if needed.

Comment: Is not possible/recommended to use Angular anything else than pure SPA? I have had assumption that I can also use Angular 2 as a component on a regular page just like I was able to do in Angular 1.

Comment: @Sakuto Here's the problem. I don't want angular in multiple html files, but I _do_ want to have access to my css in those files. Doing auth inside of angular is complex and dumb, so I'm doing that on the server. The server treats the angular index.html as a protected page, and serves up a normal SR login page. I want my css to be accessible there. Is the only way to have angular "eject" the webpack config and do it there? That kind of blows as it instantly breaks a lot of the CLI functionality...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your case, but I have one CLI project, where I want to run different sample apps when I run training.  I have on index.html file but multiple bootstrap TypeScript files, e.g. main1.ts, main2.ts, etc.

Then, to switch from one app to another I change the main property in angular-cli.json to point to the main file I want to run.

Comment: Not really solving my problem as I try to create hybrid solution where some part of the solution is on SPA and on some cases Angular is just a component on the regular html page or no Angular at all. It seems CLI is made SPA only?